# Twitter Profile image update with Oauth or xAuth

Tags: iphone, image, twitter, profile

I have tried to develope twitter profile image changing function with twitter API on iPhone.

But There are not libraries about this. I found jaanus / PlainOAuth and another libraries...

but I couldn't found. Anybody tell me how can I find or get information about this?

Comment: I need the exactly same thing and there are a lot of twitter objective-c tutorials when there was basic login but absolutely no information on how to do it with OAuth. Please @kye if you have found a solution during this 5 months, post it.